# In Angular, dynamic color for a chip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-directive

It need to programmatically set the color of a chip in Angular Material.

Let's say that each chip shows an item defined as:

```
{
  name: 'the name',
  active: true
}
```

And the chip should be gray if it is not active and red if it is. The obvious way to do this would be:

```
<md-chips ng-model="data.items" readonly="true">
  <md-chip-template ng-class="$chip.active ? 'active' : ''">
    {{$chip.name}}
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

But this won't work. It will only color the *inside* of the chip. It does not actually modify the `md-chip` tag, just the `md-chip-template` inside of it.

So why not use static chips? I could do:

```
<md-chips ng-model="data.items" readonly="true">
  <md-chip ng-repeat="chip in data.items" ng-class="$chip.active ? 'active' : ''">
    {{chip.name}}
  </md-chip>
</md-chips>
```

But that won't work either. You can't use `ng-repeat` inside of `ng-chips`. It just deletes everything you try to repeat.

So, I got to this idea. Use a directive that will update the parent of its elements on change!

```
<md-chips ng-model="data.items" readonly="true">
  <md-chip-template ng-class="$chip.active ? 'active' : ''" chip-style>
    {{$chip.name}}
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

The directive **`chipStyle`** should look up its parent with the tag `md-chip` when its model is changed and copy to it whether it has the `active` style.

Is this a good idea? Even if it is, I have not been able to call a function bound to the directive when the `data.items` array changes.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how can I do it?

The idea is that when `data.item[someIndex].active` changes on `$apply`, the class of the `md-chip` (not `md-chip-template`!) changes too. Surely, it must be possible!

The function to run would look like:

```
if (element.hasClass('active')) {
  element.parents('md-chip').addClass('active');
} else {
  element.parents('md-chip').removeClass('active');
}
```

But I can't call it automatically when the data changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can definitely do what you want with a directive, but I agree it's a bit complicated.

The way I could achieve it:

**HTML**

```
<md-chips ng-model="chips" readonly="true">
  <md-chip-template is-active active="{{$chip.active}}">
    <b>{{$chip.name}}</b>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

*isActive* **directive**

```
app.directive('isActive', function() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, el, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('active', function(val) {
        if (val === 'true')
          el.parent().parent().addClass('active');
        else
          el.parent().parent().removeClass('active');
      });
    }

    return directive;
});
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZzzey): I'm using `$timeout` to change the `active` status of the first 2 chips, just to emulate that you can indeed change it and have their background changed as well.

Comment: I didn't know about `$observe`! This makes a lot of sense. Thanks! (And `$observe` is useful to know in general.)